# Excel: conditional COUNTIF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif, conditional-statements

How can I evolve `=COUNTIF(A:A;"foobar")` so that if the cell in column A is empty, it looks (for the "foobar") in column B?

Answer (score 5):

`=COUNTIF(A:A;"foobar")+COUNTIFS(A:A;"";B:B;"foobar")`

Answer (score 0):

*You may use this formula also:*

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A7,"Foobar")=0,COUNTIF(B2:B7,"Foobar"),COUNTIF(A2:A7,"Foobar"))
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*